# Статически слинковать zlib и boost

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

Как статически слинковать zlib с boost.
Компилировал командой:

```
b2.exe link=static --with-iostreams -s ZLIB_SOURCE=G:\libraries\zlib-1.2.11
```

Даёт:

```
libboost_zlib-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib
libboost_zlib-vc141-mt-1_64.lib
```

Также пробовал для статической линковки добавить #define BOOST_IOSTREAMS_NO_LIB.
Не помогло(.
Буду признателен, если ткнете в решение, ибо сам допереть чет не могу.

Comment: Что заставляет Вас думать, что эти библиотеки являются библиотеками импорта, а не полными статическими библиотеками?

Comment: 2 .lib файла без ключа -s в названии, ведь, как правило, все остальные статические либы буста его имеют. Невозможность линковки программы с ключом /MT, используя данные(указанные в посте) либы.

Comment: Судя по сайту [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) `s` означает, что сама библиотека статически слинокована с CRT, т.е. это не то, что Вам нужно, как я понимаю.

Comment: Рядом с этими файлами есть соответствующие DLL?

Comment: Значит я ошибся. Подскажите, какой флаг указать b2.exe для статической линковки с CRT.

Comment: `runtime-link=static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, я перепутал *статическую линковку самой библиотеки(zlib)* со *статической линковки boost с crt*. Помогло решение от @ixSci - надо было добавить b2.exe флаг runtime-link=static.